# Infinity как заменить при деление на ноль

Tags: javascript, html, css

При делении на ноль результат выдает "Infinity". Как сделать так, чтобы вместо Infinity, в окошке писалось "На ноль делить нельзя!", либо выскакивал alert с данным сообщением? Вот код калькулятора:

```
<input type="button" value=" &#247; " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '/';checkLength(this);checkDivToZero(this);" />


function checkDivToZero(input) //функція ділення
{
    var value = input.value;
    if (input.value =='Infinity')
    {
    alert("Divide by zero error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то я не вижу тут функции деления

Comment: Предлагаю сделать функцию принимающую 2 агрумента, числитель и знаменатель, и проверять знаменатель на равенство нулю, если равен 0 - вывод ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
function checkDivToZero(input) //функція ділення
    {
        var value = input.value;
        if (!isFinite(input.value))
        {
        alert("Divide by zero error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Infinity` это одно из специальных значений для `Number`, кроме того у вас синтаксическая ошибка в строке `if (input.value typeof Infinity)` так писать нельзя

Comment: Я еще раз повторюсь: _Infinity это одно из специальных значений Number_ - нет такого типа, соответственно условие `if (typeof input.value == 'Infinity')` всегда будет возвращать `false`

Comment: ну и если присмотреться внимательнее - `input` в данном контексте - это кнопка, у которой значение `value=" &#247; "`

Comment: не-не `!isFinite` правильно было. Но тут это все равно не поможет потому что тут не проверяется число

Comment: Это правильная функция, если в нее передать результат действия. Ох и долго ж я к этому шел...)

Comment: ну да, если б в инпуте было значение нормальное. Но судя по всему тут подход вообще не верен

Comment: @Grundy а в чем проблема использовать `5/0 === Infinity`, работает корректно. Аналогично с `undefined`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, `input.value` - это строка: `isFinite('5/0') -> false`, `isFinite('5/1') -> false`. ну и судя по предоставленному коду `input.value=== '/'`

Comment: @Grundy eval(5/0 === Infinity) :D Что за ерунда производить математические операции с помощью строк

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, ну тут даже `eval` нет. просто непонятно откуда выдранный кусок непонятно что делающий. _Что за ерунда производить математические операции с помощью строк_ - так калькулятор же - пользователь вводит и получает ответ. Только реализация какая-то не очень